# как узнать scrollBottom?

Tags: javascript

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
 var d = p.scrollHeight - p.scrollTop - p.clientHeight.
  console.log(d);
});
```

```css
p{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<p>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita molestiae, possimus voluptate obcaecati rerum tempora quam natus distinctio. Rerum harum laboriosam dolor omnis quis velit eum, illum atque, a ad laudantium eos at aliquid! Quidem vel consequuntur delectus aut fugiat. Totam maiores excepturi voluptatum nobis iste repudiandae accusantium eaque soluta nihil a vitae dolores impedit sit veritatis rerum sed vero incidunt assumenda odio distinctio, similique officia, possimus illo? Reiciendis quidem atque illo delectus nam quisquam veniam, tempore ad enim dolores, tenetur obcaecati nemo sequi fugit rerum accusamus asperiores ipsam quia suscipit. Molestiae consequuntur doloremque aspernatur optio odio quidem aut aliquam.

</p>
<button>31</button>
```